# how to generally reference a django url that has parameter

Tags: django, django-views

It's my urls.py

```
app_name = "medicalrecord"
urlpatterns = [
    path("filesharing/<str:username>/", views.FileSharingView, name="FileSharingView"),
]
```

in my css.html

```
...
{% url 'medicalrecord:FileSharingView' "IDK" as medicalrecord_file_sharing %}
...
{% if request.path == medicalrecord_file_sharing %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'medicalrecord/css/filesharing.css' %}">
{% endif %}
```

**IDK** what to put there, any username i put it only matches that one, how to set it dynamic ?

Comment: "dynamic" as in the username of the currently logged in user? `request.uer.username`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for replay! nope it takes the other user username from url

Answer (score 1):

To set it **dynamically** you can use your **URL template tag** something like this:

```html
{% url 'medicalrecord:FileSharingView' request.user.username as medicalrecord_file_sharing %}
```

Pay attention I haven't put any **single** or **double** quote in `request.user.username`. You can read more about built-in template tags [here in django's docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)